# Postgres - If not exists not working in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently building a query and apparently, it doesn't work. This is my current query (this is the full one)

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM invite WHERE uid=$1::uuid) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO invite (uid, link) VALUES ($1::uuid, $2::text);
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM invite WHERE uid=$1::uuid;
END
```

In my console, i'm getting `syntax error at or near "IF"`

Comment: You are trying to run this code as is?

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code. `EXISTS` doesn't work like that. `IF` syntax is wrong. `SELECT` must have `INTO var` clause. It's totally not PostgreSQL syntax.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I tried multiple things such as adding `DO $$ BEGIN ... END $$;` but with them i'm getting

`bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0` when i do that.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many errors in your code:

- plpgsql code can return result only from function (not from DO)
- IF clause must have THEN
- you do not need BEGIN / END in each statement inside IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END (not error also has no sense)

Probably is better to do this by pure SQL:

```
WITH q AS (
    SELECT *
      FROM invite
     WHERE uid=$1::uuid
), i AS (
    INSERT INTO invite (uid, link)
    SELECT $1::uuid, $2::text
    WHERE (SELECT count(*) = 0 FROM q)
    RETURNING *
) SELECT * FROM q
UNION SELECT * FROM i
```